# Notation of Maxwell relations

Tags: thermodynamics, notation, differentiation

The [Maxwell relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations) are often given as for example

$$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S = -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V.$$

What does the $S$ and the $V$ in the index of the parantheses mean? I guess that $S$ and $V$ should stay constant for the derivation, but is this not already in the definition of the partial derivative?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations Best place to solve this doubt.

Comment: It does not explain the notation, does it?

Comment: The derivation part makes it pretty clear as to what the variables mean and what the notations are

Comment: There are many more than two parameters used in thermodynamics.  This just makes clear exactly which ones are being held constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically in Thermodynamics different functions get the same name if they refer to the same quantity. So, for example, the inner energy $U(p,V,N)$ and $U(T,V,N)$ both are called $U$ although they are **not** the same function.

To my understanding this is why you write the constant variables next to the brackets. It's used to further differentiate between the different functions.

Answer (score 4):

Your system has two degrees of freedom. So any of your quantities $V$, $E$, $P$, $T$, $S$ can be viewed as a function of any two of the others. The expression
$$\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_S$$
means "the derivative of $T$ with respect to $V$ when viewing it as a function of $V$ and $S$ (i.e. $T(V,S)$)". Likewise
$$\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_V$$
is the derivative of $P(S,V)$ with respect to $S$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a common notation for partial derivatives. The index means that you take the partial derivative while holding the index variable (of the parenthesis) constant.